# How to calculate LY same week sales when i have only weekid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have have sales table which has weekid. I wanted to calculate LY same week sales. how can i achieve.

```
select * from
tblsales TY
outer join
tblsales LY 
on TY.weekid-52=LY.weekid
```

is the only solution . Full outer join takes a lot of time.

Comment: is your weekid indexed? if not, add an index.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here , whats wrong with group by?

Comment: why is group by coming into picture. i Was checking if i can bring LY sames week sales as  a new column by doing full outer join. my issue with full outer join is it has many years data and table is huge so checking any other options apart from full outer join